# autosys job error

Tags: jobs, autosys

We have a set of autosys jobs already on our server and now we are trying to set up a new autosys job, but unable to succeed due to an error with the “Owner” field. The old/existing jobs on the server are working fine. But for the new one it’s not allowing us to set the same owner which the existing ones have. Following is the error while loading the new job.

```
CAUAJM_I_50204 Inserting/Updating Job: down_time_tracker
CAUAJM_W_10225 Only the CA Unicenter AutoSys JM EDIT superuser can set the owner.
CAUAJM_E_10302 Database Change WAS NOT successful.
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue isn't with the value of the "owner" field.  The problem is that you don't have permissions to set the "owner" field.

When you set up the old jobs, were you logged in as the same user?  Have the policies regarding autosys access changed since the old jobs were set up?

On a side note, you'll probably find better answers for these types of questions on Server Fault.

Comment: The old jobs were created by someone who is not available now. so how can I create a new job with same username?

Comment: Log in as that owner or as the Autosys JM superuser ID.